# Configuring arrow keys on media

Tags: shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I just installed Ubuntu and I'm extremely happy about it, I can see myself switching to Linux from Windows permanently.

There's a slight problem however, when I'm watching a movie, arrow keys skip forward by 1 minute. Is it possible to configure this?

If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you be a little more specific as to which program you are using when this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the default video player (called [Gnome Videos (was Totem)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Videos)), this feature is in [the Wishlist category](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/593209). <strike>It's marked *In Progress* after about 4 years, so there's no telling when it might actually arrive.</strike> It's not going to happen. According to [Bastien Nocera [totem developer]](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=417141#c14):

> I don't want to see options like that in Totem. FWIW, use Shift+Left Arrow if
>   you want to skip back by 5 seconds.
>
> ... I rejected a patch to make the arrow keys skip time configurable.

If you do wish to configure, you might want to look at alternatives such as [VLC](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/vlc/), [SMPlayer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/smplayer/), etc.

In VLC, the option is available, but hidden away. Go to the *Tools* menu and open *Preferences*. In the bottom-left corner, change *Show Settings* from *Simple* to *All*, and search for `hotkeys`:
[image: VLC Advanced preferences dialog]

Set the jump lengths to the duration you want (in seconds).
You can also change the shortcuts for the jumps. (This option is also available in the *Simple* interface under the *Hotkeys* section - only the jump duration needs the advanced view.)

Comment: Thanks I've installed VLC do you happen to know where I can find the option to configure the keys?

Comment: That bug report appears more to do with the playback speed, not skipping... I know that mentions it, but this does not fully resolve the issue.

Comment: @Wilf yes, but someone posted a patch which dealt with that *and* one that dealt with skip time configuration. The second patch was rejected. Please read through. Or at least read the line I quoted, which explicitly states why the dev rejected the patch.