# Manually setting skip distance for Totem

Tags: totem

Is there a way to manually set the skip distance in Totem when using the left/right arrow keys besides the default -15s/+60s (-5s/+15s when used with Shift) like one could on VLC (Not to mention setting the hotkeys themselves)?

Comment: Not gonna happen. See [Configuring arrow keys on media](http://askubuntu.com/questions/515634/configuring-arrow-keys-on-media)